# Finding the set of limit points in a set with dictionary order

Tags: general-topology

What would the interior set of $((\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}] \times [0,\frac{1}{2}))$ be in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ under the dictionary topology?

My understanding is that it would look like:
$((\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}) \times (0,\frac{1}{2}))$ but I am not sure how to prove that this is true, or if its even correct. Wouldn't $\frac{1}{3}$ need to be less than $0$ on the dictionary order topology?

And how would I use those interior sets to find the limit points of that set?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What tools are available to you?  Where are you stuck?  Please **edit the question** to add this information.  Questions that show no evidence of an independent effort to reach a solution usually are not well received here.

Comment: @RobertShore This is what I am stuck on. Not sure if I am trying to prove a false statement or not.

Comment: You do not have the interior correct.  Consider, for various points on the geometric boundaries of your set, what’s required for a point to have both smaller and larger (in the dictionary order) points also in the set.  It would be helpful for you to further edit your question to state the definition you’re using for the dictionary topology.

Comment: In particular, consider the point $({1\over2},0)$.